# Can angels become tamei?

Tags: tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, malach-angel

What it says on the tin really.
Are there any sources dealing with the question of angels and tumah?

Comment: MIshna keilim 17:14

Comment: @DoubleAA Nice mekor. But it doesn't mention Melachim in any of the mefarshim for day two or etc... Therefore it's not shayach